# Prototype New Observer after Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, prototypejs

I have two Prototype JS observers in a section that depending of other user actions may change in the content but not the structure of the divs. The issue is that the divs that contain both elements change dynamically through an ajax call (). Therefore my code only works one time, and after the ajax call (new Ajax.Request(url, {parameters...) everything stop working even when the elements have the same class name, divs structure, etc.

To be more specific this is what I have:

```
<!-- COD Hck -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$$('.pm_cashondelivery').invoke('on','click','.pm_cashondelivery', function(event, el){
    $('id_flatrate_flatrate').setStyle({'display': 'block'});
    $$('.metodose').each(
                        function(elem){
                            elem.checked=false;
                        });

    $('s_method_flatrate_flatrate').checked=true;

    $$('.mayor').each(
        function(elem){
            elem.setStyle({'display': 'none'})
        });

});

$$('.metrest').invoke('on', 'click','.metrest', function(event, el){
    $('id_flatrate_flatrate').setStyle({'display': 'none'});
    $$('.metodose').each(
                        function(elem){
                            elem.checked=false;
                        });

    $$('.mayor').each(
        function(elem){
            elem.setStyle({'display': 'block'})
        });

    $$('.mayor input').each(

                        function(elem){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                elem.setAttribute('checked',true);
                                },1);
                            elem.checked=true;//Check double time due Chrome bug
                        });
});
</script>
```

The first observer is: `$$('.pm_cashondelivery').invoke('on','click','.pm_cashondelivery', function(event, el){` . The second observer is `$$('.metrest').invoke('on', 'click','.metrest', function(event, el){` . I need this observers still working even after the ajax call in the same divs. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

If the `div.pm_cashondelivery` and `div.metrest` elements are being recreated with each Ajax request, then you need to find an element further up the document tree to attach your delegated event handlers to.

For example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".pm_cashondelivery", function(event) {
    // ...
});

$(document).on("click", ".metrest", function(event) {
    // ...
});
```